# MBed program gets stuck

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, mbed

I have written some code with the help of Mbed framework, which is either supposed to take user input and then display sensor values or display the value after 15mins. When I try to execute this code, it is getting stuck at line 21 (display.printf("Inside loop\n");).

I am not able to understand why is it so and what is the fix for this problem so that the switch block gets executed. How to I solve this? FYI, although not important, the microcontroller I am using is STM32 bluepill (STM32F103C8T6).

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Sensor_input.h"
#include "Ticker.h"
#include "Dht11.h"

//#include "USBSerial.h"
Serial display(PA_2, PA_3, 9600);
char* a;
Dht11 DhtSensor(PA_4);
Ticker t;
Sensor_input Soil(PB_7, PB_6, 8);
float *SensorData;
void getSensorData();
int main ( void ){

    uint8_t choice = 0;

    display.printf("Enter 1 or 2:\n1.Greenhouse stats\n2.Return Control to System");
    choice = display.putc(display.getc());
    while(1){
        display.printf("Inside loop\n");
        wait_ms(15000);
        switch(choice)
        {
            
            case 1:
                display.printf("Inside case 1");
                a = Soil.readTemp();
                display.printf("Temperature: %f\n",DhtSensor.getCelsius());
                display.printf("Humidity: %f\n",DhtSensor.getHumidity());
                display.printf("Soil water content: %c\n ",*a);
                break;
            case 2:
                /*<GreenHouse object>*/
                /*Might have to proceed with timer*/
                display.printf("Inside case 2");
                t.attach(&getSensorData,4500);
                display.printf("Temperature: %f\n",a[0]);
                display.printf("Humidity: %f\n",a[1]);
                display.printf("Soil water content: %c\n ",a[2]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            
        }
    }
}
void getSensorData(){
    static float a[3];
    a[0]=DhtSensor.getCelsius();
    a[1]=DhtSensor.getHumidity();
    a[2]=(int)Soil.readTemp();   

}
```

Comment: I just got to know that the flow is jumping to the default case in the switch case block. Unable to figure out why the 'choice' variable didn't get any value even after user input.

Comment: How does `wait_ms()` work?  Does it rely on a hardware timer?  Where is that hardware timer initialized?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct or not, but I think wait_ms() uses a software timer.

Comment: `getSensorData` is a dead function with no side effects. `a` in the main loop is an uninitialized pointer. Neither makes any sense.

Comment: `choice = display.putc(display.getc());` How do you know that this doesn't return EOF? (assuming this works like stdio.h)

Comment: `wait_ms()` is an moved V2 function and deprecated since moved v5.  What version are you using?

Comment: There is as per comments much wrong with this code besides the wait function, if that is even truly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement is probably being executed, but always in the 'default' case. You can test this out by putting a print statement in the default.

When you request a char from the display, it will return the input as an ASCII-character. This means, if you enter '1' on the display, it will give you (as the ASCII table says) 0x31 (decimal 49) and not the value of 1. So you have to change your case to "case '1':" or "case 0x31:" and the equivalent for the second case.